# MVC - Kendo Grid and DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

In EditorTemplates I have defined my dropdownlist as

```
    @model int?

    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
     .Name("id_sifra")
     .DataValueField("id_sifra")
     .DataTextField("naziv")
     .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Read("Read_SifreDL","Documents").ServerFiltering(true) )
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:400px" })
     .OptionLabel("---Select---")
    )
```

In the grid I have

```
columns.Bound(c => c.id_sifra).EditorTemplateName("_SifreEditor").Title("id_sifra");
```

The Read_SifreDL in DocumentsControllers is

```
public JsonResult Read_SifreDL()
{
    var sifre = db.Sifre.Select(c => new
    {
        id_sifra = c.id,
        naziv = c.naziv
    }).ToList();

    return Json(sifre, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The problem is when I do a selection in dropdownlist (in this case it is **naziv**), and the dropdownlist has closed the valuefield is shown (in this case it is **id_sifra**). I want **naziv** to be shown. What is wrong in my approach?

Comment: Shouldn't `.Title("id_sifra")` on your grid be `.Title("naziv")`?

Comment: I've rename it but result is the same... :( When it got focus the **name** is shown, but when it lost  focus the **id_sifra** is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Add `naziv`in your model and,

```
columns.Bound(c => c.id_sifra).EditorTemplateName("_SifreEditor").Title("naziv").ClientTemplate("#:naziv#");;
```

Comment: How do you mean to add `naziv`? I have autogenerated model. Where to put `naziv`?

Comment: I mean to the model you binded the grid with

Comment: But this entity doesn't contain field **naziv**. **naziv** is in another table.

Comment: you can create a view model that contains all properties that you need with the grid. Then bind your grid this view model